# Can we access(open-read/write) driver file /dev/aaa using java?

Tags: java, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

Kindly please some one explain can we access driver file(open-read/write) in linux eg:`/dev/aaa` using userspace java application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a file like any other so yes, you will be able to open it, read from/write to it (and of course, don't forget to close it too). Depending on the associated driver, you may also be able to seek, mmap etc.

But what you will *not* be able to do is send ioctls, of course. For this, native interaction is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can access it like a normal file, or if the driver allows, memory map the file and thus the device.  From a Java perspective it works like a normal file (That is the point of the `/dev/` file system) This "trick" also works for `/proc/` btw.